# Modifying file contents without creating a new version

Tags: document-library, versioning

I have a job that runs every five minutes and puts some information to the footer of the Word documents. Versioning is enabled on the list so whenever the job runs, a new version is created for every document.

Is there a way to modify the documents without creating new versions every time?

Currently, I am reading the file contents with `SPFile.OpenBinary()`, modifying the stream, then putting the file back with `file.ParentFolder.Files.Add(fileName, stream)`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call SystemUpdate(false) method to update the item without incrementing the version number. More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx

Comment: But I am not updating the item. I am not calling item.Update() anywhere. Just pulling the binary stream then putting it back as I wrote in my question.

Comment: When you call add method, a new file is upload and if file name is same a new version is created. I am not sure you can avoid a new version in that case.

Comment: So, is there any way for modifying the contents of the file other that requires adding file to parent file collection?

Comment: The File itself exists as special kind of attachment in the `ListItem`. If you modify the file you must call `Update()`. If you don't want a new version created, you must call `SystemUpdate(false)`. Test this out and see if it still creates a new version.

Comment: I am not working on the list item. I get the item, open it's attachment by calling item.File.OpenBinaryStream(). So item itself is not updated anywhere. When I am finished working on the file, I put it back to file collection of parent folder. So I am not calling listItem.Update() or listItem.SystemUpdate(). Those calls are not needed in my case. But a new version is automatically created when I put the file in parent folder.

Answer (score 2):

All of your posts helped me build a solution.

We are using the Client Object Model (COM) and cannot refer to SharePoint.dll which has the SPList object. In our given scope of COM, I could accomplish it by doing this in the C# code.

1. Load the File and check out

   ```
           clientContext.Load(file);
           file.CheckOut(); // Check out the File
           clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   ```
2. Update our file properties as follows:

   ```
           file.ListItemAllFields["Owner"] = "Owner Name";
           file.ListItemAllFields["Field"] = "Value";
   ```
3. Finally Update the List Item and Check in the file as shown below

   ```
           file.ListItemAllFields.Update(); // Update the Properties
           // Checkin the file with Overwrite to maintain the version
           file.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn); 
           clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   ```

Hope this helps some one.

Comment: Ravi, is this answer related to the question above? I am not sure if you answered the correct question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep the version, it seems you no longer need the unmodified file. 
You can delete(SPFileCollection.Delete) the file and add the modified one after that.